# how to registration page execute once when user install application

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

How to execute registration page once when user install application.
i have implement by using shared prefrences, but after resume activity registartion page is not showing...
one more thing after remove cache registartion page is showing
i dont know why it's happen 
please anyone know about how to do it
this registration page implementing my app that will execte after installing app only for once...again never appear
i dont know why it's happen

splash_activity.java
this is the method will execute only once after installing application
this method is define in splash activity code because after installing of app call regitaration activity only for once

```
 public void Firsttimexecute()
    {
        SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);
        boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);
        if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time
        //Splash will load for first time
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true);
            editor.commit();
            Intent i=new Intent(Splash_Activity.this,Regsitration_Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {

            Intent a=new Intent(Splash_Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to share you current code for us to understand the reason behind this behavior

Comment: Remember to properly format your code and be as descriptive about the problem as possible. Also, try to avoid asking for help as we already know thats what you are here for.

Comment: sorry sir for that...

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing and testing app using Android Studio then remember that even though Studio will uninstall the app and reinstall it, it will not remove app cache (including SharedPreferences). So, if you need to remove SharedPreference while testing you will need to either:

1. Remove app data yourself
2. Manually uninstall the app

Comment: but sir problem is that after clear cache again appear reg activity

Comment: Yes, that will happen. You have to store whether it was a first_time app launch or not. You can either store it locally (local database/SharedPreference/File) or remotely on your server. Remember that any local storage is user's and hence can be deleted by her anytime. Hence, unless you setup a web database for storing this info (which is really NOT recommended for these cases anyway) this is unavoidable.